# Can I use GCC's / LLVM's STL headers with VS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl, llvm, llvm-clang

I am using MSVC++ 2013, and I installed the [Clang](https://github.com/ishani/ClangVSx) plugin.

However, since I'm using STL, [I'm getting bugs like this one](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17926):

```
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\map:6:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtree(1667,3) :  error: cannot compile this try statement yet
            _TRY_BEGIN
            ^~~~~~~~~~
```

[image: actual code]

They are quite a lot. In fact, there's only problems on the header files -- and it's what has me confused.

Is this an actual compiler bug? Incompatibility with MS' STL implementation?

If so, can I fix it, and how?

I thought of using GCC's or LLVM's headers, but I don't know how -- any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All standard libraries use compiler-specific extensions to work.  Clang doesn't understand the MSVC extensions, nor would MSVC be able to use gcc/clang libraries. clang and gcc try to have the same extensions, so they can use the same libraries.  You'll have to tell the extension to use GCC/clang compatible headers, but I don't know how.

Comment: @MooingDuck well, I'm using `clang-cl.exe` -- isn't it exactly made for this?

Comment: Did not know about that feature.  http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#clang-cl says "it should be executed inside a Visual Studio Native Tools Command Prompt or a regular Command Prompt where the environment has been set up using e.g. vcvars32.bat", is that being done?

Comment: @MooingDuck it is, but it fails to compile MSVC's headers -- which is why I'm unable to compile my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you insist the environment is set up right, I looked up that exact macro that's not understood.  That particular error can occur when the MSVC headers themselves include xstddef when `_HAS_EXCEPTIONS` is defined as `0`.  I can't find any other conditions on that macro, so it appears that your clang is compiling without exceptions.

This rings a bell in my head, and Clang had problems with exceptions for a long time on windows. Occording to this link, it still does in MSVC compatability mode: "Exceptions and SEH: Minimal. Clang can parse both constructs, but does not know how to emit compatible handlers. Clang cannot throw exceptions but it can rethrow them." http://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think llvm's libc++ can be compiled with msvc. Your best bet would be to try to use LLVM to produce MSVC compatible code that can (in theory) be linked with Visual C++ compiled code.

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html